# Copy Trello Board or Reoccurring Use

Tags: trello

I manufacture boats.  I'm trying to use Trello to track each boat as it's built (lists are Parts Ordered, Received, Tasks To Do, Tasks in Progress, Tasks Done, etc).  It's working great and it's easy to use.

However, I need to do this for each boat built (I can have two or three being built at the same time) and each has a specific hull number and needs its own board.  I don't want to (really can't time-wise) recreate all the cards and lists each time a new boat (new hull number) is started (there are a LOT of cards!).

I really need a master board template to copy each time a new boat is started to populate the new board.  Trello is a perfect tool for tracking my building process (the best I've found so far) and would be "the" perfect tool if I could overcome this one issue.  Is there a way to do this?  I'm sure it would be helpful to a lot of applications where a project is repeated.

Answer (score 6):

The Trello staff is working on this feature at the moment. You can follow their process at the [Trello Development board](https://trello.com/board/trello-development/4d5ea62fd76aa1136000000c).

Specifically for your case, see [this card](https://trello.com/c/lWSNwhdM).

*UPDATE*

According to the [Trello Blog](http://blog.trello.com/you-can-copy-boards-now-finally/): they've done it!